# Display dictionary in a reverse list

Tags: c#, dictionary, reverse

What I want to do is to display my dictionary in the reverse list: simple as that.

```
static Dictionary<string, Team> teams = new Dictionary<string, Team>();

static void AllTeams()
{
    Console.WriteLine("=============== Teams ===============");
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Team> keyValue in teams)
    {
           
        Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Team> keyValue in teams.Reverse())`

Comment: A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not ordered, so you want to print the reverse of which order?

Comment: use StringBuilder, and add the key backwards.

Answer (score 0):

As you in example using only `Keys` (`string`s) for output, so you can reverse or order only by `Keys` in next ways:

```
void Main(string[] args = default)
{
    teams.Add("BTeam", null);
    teams.Add("HTeam", null);
    teams.Add("ATeam", null);
    teams.Add("STeam", null);
    teams.Add("4Team", null);
    teams.Add("ZTeam", null);

    Console.WriteLine("=============== Teams (Original) ===============");

    foreach (string key in teams.Keys)
        Console.WriteLine(key);

    Console.WriteLine("=============== Teams (Reversed) ===============");

    foreach (string key in teams.Keys.Reverse())
        Console.WriteLine(key);

    Console.WriteLine("=============== Teams (Ordered ascending) ===============");

    foreach (string key in teams.Keys.OrderBy(x => x))
        Console.WriteLine(key);

    Console.WriteLine("=============== Teams (Ordered descending) ===============");

    foreach (string key in teams.Keys.OrderByDescending(x => x))
        Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Only that you need - add a `using System.Linq;` to access `.Reverse()`, `.OrderBy(...)` and `.OrderByDescending(...)` extension methods.